# Better way to print out rows from a datatable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dataset, iteration

I am new to vb.net and I am trying to query a database and print out the records in the row to the console window.  I got it to work, but I have a feeling that there is a more concise way to do this.  One thing that I am sure is wrong is that I had to convert the dataset to a datatable to be able to retrieve the values.  Is that correct?  Could you take a look at the code below (especially the for loop) and let me know what I can improve upon?

Thanks!

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim constring As String = "Data Source=C:\Users\test\Desktop\MyDatabase1.sdf"
    Dim conn As New SqlCeConnection(constring)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT")
    Dim adapter As New SqlCeDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        adapter.Fill(ds, "testds")
        cmd.Dispose()
        adapter.Dispose()
        conn.Close()

        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables.Item("testds")
        Dim row As DataRow
        Dim count As Integer = dt.Columns.Count()

        For Each row In dt.Rows
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            While i <= count - 1
                Console.Write(row(i))
                i += 1
            End While
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine())
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("There was an error")
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would rewrite this for a few reasons:

1) You should always use `Using` statements with disposable objects to ensure they are correctly cleaned up. You had a good start with the dispose commands, but this way is safer.

2) It is more efficient to use `ExecuteReader` than loading everything into a dataset.

3) Your try/catch statement should include object creation as well as execution.

Finally, in response to your question about datasets and datatables, that code was absolutely correct: a dataset consists of zero or more datatables, so you were just extracting the existing datatable from the dataset.

```
    Try
        Dim constring As String = "Data Source=C:\Users\test\Desktop\MyDatabase1.sdf"

        Using conn As New SqlCeConnection(constring)
            conn.Open()
            Using cmd As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT", conn)
                Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Do While reader.Read
                    For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                        Console.Write(reader.GetString(i))
                    Next
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine())
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("There was an error")
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

One last note: since you are just printing to the console, it doesn't matter as much, but whenever you deal with a lot of strings, especially those that are to be concatenated, you should always consider using [System.Text.StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Here is an example rewrite of the loop that prints to the console using stringbuilder (builds the string in memory, then dumps it to the console; I have also added the field name for good measure):

```
 Dim sbOutput As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500)
 For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
     If sbOutput.Length <> 0 Then
         sbOutput.Append("; ")
     End If
     sbOutput.Append(reader.GetName(i)).Append("=").Append(reader.GetString(i))
 Next
 sbOutput.AppendLine()
 Console.Write(sbOutput.ToString)
```